Regarding Lemma 2.43 in Folland's real analysis
Consider the collection $\mathcal Q_k$ of dyadic cubes of sides $2^{-k}$ with vertices in the lattice $(2^{-k}\mathbb Z)^n\subset \mathbb R^n$. Let $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ be open and define $\underline{A}(U,k)$ to be the union of the cubes that are contained in $U$. Then $\underline{A}(U,k)$ is increasing with $k$. Define $\underline{A}(U)=\bigcup_1^\infty \underline{A}(U,k)$.
Now, I'm reading Lemma 2.43 in Folland's real analysis text which states that $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ open is a countable union of cubes with disjoint interior. He has already proved that we in fact have $U=\underline{A}(U)$ and thus $$\underline{A}(U)=\underline{A}(U,0)\cup\bigcup_1^\infty [\ \underline{A}(U,k)\setminus \underline{A}(U,k-1)\ ].$$Then $\underline{A}(U,0)$ is a (countable) union of cubes in $\mathcal Q_0$, and for $k\geq 1$, the closure of $\underline{A}(U,k)\setminus \underline{A}(U,k-1)$ is a (countable) union of cubes in $\mathcal Q_k$. These cubes all have disjoint interiors and the result follows.
My question is, why does the author mention the closure of $\underline{A}(U,k)\setminus \underline{A}(U,k-1)$? What relevance does the closure have here? This word confuses me. I understand why we need to take $\underline{A}(U,k)\setminus \underline{A}(U,k-1)$ in the big union, since otherwise we might be overcounting some area (see image below), though I don't understand the use of the word closure here.
Here's a sketch of the unit circle.


I think I understand . If you take a look at the figure above, then if we remove $\underline{A}(U, k - 1)$ from $\underline{A}(U, k)$, we are removing some boundary of the cubes and hence I don't think they will be closed anymore. But the closure of $\underline{A}(U, k) \setminus \underline{A}(U, k - 1)$ will be a union of closed cubes in $\mathcal Q_k$. The union $$\underline{A}(U, 0)\cup\bigcup_1^\infty [ \ \underline{A}(U, k) \setminus \underline{A}(U, k - 1) \ ]$$ will also be a (countable) union of closed cubes (with disjoint interiors).
